# String replacement, regular expressions

Tags: regex, krl

I'd like to do string replacement in the `pre` block of a rule using regular expressions. I know there is a function to do that, but I can't find it. Hints?

I'm thinking something like this:

```
origStr = "Original-string-has-hyphens";
newStr = origStr.replace(re/-/ /g);
```

The result being that `newStr = "Original string has hyphens"`.

EDIT: Just realized that I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741861/krl-rss-parser-handle-encoding-issues) a few months ago, but I never quite got a working answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation can be found at http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Replace
I found it using my Kynetx docs search tool http://supersearcher.michaelgrace.org/

Comment: Thanks, Mike. You should make that super searcher an extension for docs.kynetx.com. :)

Comment: The plan is to eventually just put it in the docs once the team has enough time. : )

Answer (score 1):

what about `origStr.replace("-", " ");`